# In over my head with Java networking

Tags: java, networking

I'm doing a project for a class where we are creating a game that can be played with 2-4 players over a LAN.  Even though none of our group members had ever done any Java networking before we stupidly decided that it wouldn't be that hard to figure out.  Anyway, the job of getting the networking working fell to me, but I am totally lost on how to do it.  I can't find any tutorials online except really basic things like passing a string from a single client to a server.  So I have a couple of questions.

First, how do I connect multiple clients to a server.  Do I need to create a new `ServerSocket` for each?

Second, are there any easy to use libraries out there that can abstract some of this for me?

I know these are probably pretty basic questions, but I truly have done a fair bit of reading and I'm still getting no where.

Answer (score 2):

[Akka](http://akka.io/)'s [remote actors](http://doc.akka.io/remote-actors-java) might help.  Here's an example of a basic client-server connection:

```
// server code
class HelloWorldActor extends UntypedActor {
   public void onReceive(Object msg) {
      getContext().replySafe(msg + " World");
   }
}
remote().start("localhost", 9999).register(
   "hello-service", 
    actorOf(HelloWorldActor.class));

// client code
ActorRef actor = remote().actorFor(
   "hello-service", "localhost", 9999);
Object res = actor.sendRequestReply("Hello");
```

Akka does raise the abstraction level, much like RPC, so that it seems like you're just interacting with local objects.  It will also help with concurrency and scalability, but those may be less of a concern in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a learning exercise, I recommend against trying to find a library on top of basic sockets API. Every Java developer should know how this stuff works.

You create one ServerSocket on the server side to listen for incoming connections on the port. Sit in a loop waiting for connections. When you connect to a client, the easiest approach is to spin up a thread to manage that connection. The thread terminates when the client closes connection (or there is an io error - broken connection).

Then you need to devise the on-wire protocol. Typically you will want start each request with 4 bytes (int) representing a request type. Then interpret the rest based on request type. When encoding strings, decide if you are going to use length-based encoding or terminator-based encoding.

Actually going through the exercise of figuring out how this stuff really works will be very educational.

Comment: This might help you get started: http://oreilly.com/catalog/javanp2/chapter/ch11.html

Comment: I would typically agree with you that I should do it myself and not use a library, but the class is about software engineering not programming directly.  I only have a few weeks to do the project and the networking was only supposed to be a small part of the project so I need to get it done as quickly as possible.  Also, I'm in my last semester of school and I already have a job lined up for a company that is a .NET shop, so it's really not even that essential that I learn the intricacies of Java networking at the moment.

Comment: Basic networking principals are same regardless of the language you use. Even if you don't think you are going to utilize those skills directly, it is still very useful to understand how this stuff works. If you really want to avoid learning this, take a look at Java RPC (Remote Procedure Call). No guarantee that you will save much time this way if your communication needs are small (number of message types). Instead of learning sockets, you would be learning RPC or another messaging abstraction library.

Answer (score 1):

Although I fully agree with Konstantin that you should work with pure sockets at least once, you did mention this is for a software engineering course and I don't think you should reinvent another networking library, on top of having to write your application code.

If you want a library, [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/quick-start-guide.html) and [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) are two Java-based frameworks that are used for distributed networking.

I have used Mina before and it abstracts some of the low level socket complexities into a more event-driven framework.  Check out [this](http://mina.apache.org/quick-start-guide.html) quick-start guide with a time server example and note the simplicity of the MinaTimeServer and the TimeServerHandler classes. Just create a session in your handler and put whatever logic you need in MessageReceived().  You won't have to deal with encoding Strings to byte arrays or marshalling, etc.

I have no experience with Netty so I won't comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ServerListener extends Thread {
  ServerListener() {
    this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(53123);  // port number, best to use btw 10000 and 65000
  }
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
      // the previous line blocks until an actual client connects
      new ClientCommunicator(s).start();
    }
  }
}
class ClientCommunicator extends Thread {
  public void run () {
    while (true) {
      try {
        Message msg = s.read();
        processMessage(msg);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        // connection broke - kill this client
        clientManager.killClient(this);
      }
    }
  }
}
class Client {
  Client() {
    Socket s = new Socket ("localhost", 53123); // use the same port number
    // now start sending messages to the socket / reading messages from it
  }
}
```